# Selected row from TableView as Title on new TableView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigation, tableview, segue

I have data in my `TableView`. And I use swipe actions. When I swipe from left to right, I have the option to press "Bearbeiten". By clicking "Bearbeiten" a new `TableView` opens.

The title of the navigation controller of this new `TableView`, should have the same name as the swiped cell.

I tried it this way:

1.Create a list
   2. Add data to this list
   3. Prepare for Segue
   4. Push the first entry of the list to the new `ViewController`
   5. Add Navigation.title with data

But it doesn't work. What i am doing wrong?

MyCode:

First `TableView`:

```
....

List<string> wordnewvc = new List<string>();

....

    public UIContextualAction ContextualDefinitionAction(int row)
    {
        var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal, "Bearbeiten", (ReadLaterAction, view, success) => {

                                                                wordnewvc.Add(words[row]);

                                                                secondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("secondViewController") as secondViewController;
                                                                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);

                                                            });
        action.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
        return action;
    }


    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

        var secondViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as secondViewController;

        secondViewController.firma = wordsnewvc[0];
    }
```

Second `ViewController`:

```
        public string firma
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public secondViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        NavigationItem.Title = firma;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixd the `Navigation Push` and `Segue`

#### Solution1:Navigation Push

Method `PrepareForSegue` is no need.

```
var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal, "Bearbeiten", (ReadLaterAction, view, success) => {
    secondViewController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("secondViewController") as secondViewController;
    controller.firma = wordsnewvc[0];
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
});
```

#### Solution2:Segue

```
var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal, "Bearbeiten", (ReadLaterAction, view, success) => {
    this.PerformSegue(identifierInStoryboard, null);
});

public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
     if(segue.Identifier == identifierInStoryboard)
     {
         var secondViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as secondViewController;
         secondViewController.firma = wordsnewvc[0];
     }  
}
```